# Match parent not occupying whole width for layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I'm a bit confused why my layout is not occupying the whole width of the screen. It uses match_parent for the parent root container and the preview shows me the whole screen occupied but when I run it I see this instead, where a big block of space is shown.

[image]

I've even tried to force this using fitsSystemWindows and layout_weight but  have got no success so far.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"      
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"    
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:background="@color/shadow">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/titleAndProgressBar"
        layout="@layout/title_and_progress_bar" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvThankYouLeave"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:text="Thank you for helping us fight COVID-19. We're sorry to see you go. When you tap 'I want to leave' we will remove all data stored by the app from your device including a mobile number, if you have shared one, symptom data and any demographic health data you may have shared. Non-identifying authorisation tokens stored on the server will also be deleted.\n\nRandom IDs created or collected by Exposure Notification Services cannot be removed by the COVID Tracker app. If you wish to remove these Random IDs you can do this via your device Settings."
        android:textColor="@color/text"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/titleAndProgressBar" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvReadPrivacy"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:text="You can read the Data Protection \nInformation Notice here"
        android:textColor="@color/shadow"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/ivLockPrivacy"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/ivLockPrivacy"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/ivLockPrivacy" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivLockPrivacy"
        android:layout_width="42dp"
        android:layout_height="42dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:src="@drawable/privacy"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btnLeave"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/tvThankYouLeave"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvThankYouLeave"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnLeave"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rectangle_button"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/danger"
        android:text="I want to leave"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tvReadPrivacy"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />     
 </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

This layout in inside a host activity.

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include layout="@layout/snippet_toolbar_plain" />

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:visibility="visible">

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:defaultNavHost="true"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" />

    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottomNav"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@color/white"
        app:itemIconSize="20dp"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
        app:itemIconTint="@drawable/nav_items_color"
        app:itemTextColor="@drawable/nav_items_color"
        android:theme="@style/BottomNavigationStyle"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_menu_nav" />

</LinearLayout>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Thank you.

Comment: is this XML file loaded into another view like fragment or something?

Comment: 1- Remove layout_weight from parent tag ConstraintLayout.
2- If you are loading this XML file as a part of some other layout file then you should change the Height as match_parent there.

Comment: Hi, please refer to the updated question with the code for the host activity where this layout lives.

Comment: what happens if you remove app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"?

Comment: You're talking about the fragment XML file? Same blank space.

Comment: Which ConstraintLayout version are you using?

Comment: can you use LinearLayout instead of ConstraintLayout?

Comment: Hi, I found the answer. It was missing android:fillViewport="true" from the NestedScrollView within the activity_main file. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer. It was missing `android:fillViewport="true"` from the NestedScrollView within the activity_main file.